# Conditional type variable in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to define a variable 'type' in Scala after a conditional if-else.

The purpose is to get a variable like `type In = xxx`. With that being able to instantiate a parametrized class or call a parametrized function. Given the definitions:

```
  class MyParamClass[T: TypeTag](context: String){...}
  def startStrean[T: TypeTag](context: String) = {...}
```

I want to create an instance of `MyParamClass[T](context = "my contentx")` where T depends on a configuration string. The configuration string, is something that the user can provide using an API.

```
  val conf = Option("Map[String, Any]")

  //get the data types from the context
  type In = conf match {
    case Some("Map[String, Int]") =>      Map[String, Int]
    case Some("Map[String, Double]") =>   Map[String, Double]
    case Some("List[Double]") =>          List[Double]
    case Some("List[Int]") =>             List[Int]
    case None =>                          Map[String, Any]
  }
```

*Note*: The previous code snippet does not compile.

Then, to create the class or to execute the function:

```
val context = "my context"
val pc = new MyParamClass[In](context)
startStream[In](context)
```

Note that the Type `T` cannot be infer from the arguments types.

Looking at [Scala reflection documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) I see some ways. But, I am playing around with `tq`.

The main problem I am encountering is how to define a type variable `type In` at runtime.

Comment: What's your end goal? I'm not sure the immediate thing you're trying to do is possible, but perhaps there is another approach to solve you high-level problem.

Comment: `Map` is not a type. It's a higher-kinded type constructor.

Comment: This might be possible, but I think more info is needed. Is the value of `inConf.context` known at compile-time? Or can you modify it to be a `type` instead of an `Option[String]`?

Comment: @Andrey My understanding is that Map is an ordinary type constructor, of kind `* -> *`, not a higher-kind like Functor, but I guess that's beside the point. At any rate, the question does use "proper" types, like `Map[String, Any]`.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon then it's rather `* -> * -> *`, because it has two arguments... In any case, it's somewhere in the "set (?)" of not-necessarily-zeroary and possibly-higher-kinded type constructors, which is strictly larger than just ordinary types (of kind `*`). The first `Map` in the above list looks a bit strange... But even if it weren't there, I'm still not sure what's actually being asked, the "actual example" seems quite broken.

Comment: I have been trying to to redefine the question. @BrianMcCutchon: that variable is not known at runtime, comes from an API call and can get any os the values mentioned.

Comment: Well, you can't define a type alias at runtime. You might be able to do it at compile time by making your API call from a macro and generating the type alias there. This whole design seems suspect to me, though. Why are users of your API providing type information via strings? Why can't you take type information via normal means, like type parameters? Maybe we can suggest a better design if you give us more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: The idea is that the user specifies the format of the data that he expects to receives using an external connector. In the example above, the `startStream` function, will create an `akka-streams` graph to process some information from connector A -> f() -> B.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the previous answer since it was not actually replying to the question above. Thanks to the comments in the question I came to the following solutions that works in my case.

The issue was that types cannot be generated at runtime, only at compilation type. Therefore, I have to write the call for each of the input `conf` strings.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val tb = mirror.mkToolBox()

def typecheckType(tree: Tree): Type = tb.typecheck(tree, tb.TYPEmode).tpe

typecheckType(tq"$context") match {
        case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Map[String, _]] =>
          startStrean[Map[String, Any], Map[String, Any]](context = context)
        case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Map[String, Double]] =>
          startStrean[Map[String, Double], Map[String, Double]](context = context)
        case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Map[String, Int]] =>
          startStrean[Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int]](context = context)
        case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[List[Double]] =>
          startStrean[List[Double], List[Double]](context = context)
        case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[String] =>
          startStrean[String, String](context = context)
        case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Int] =>
          startStrean[Int, Int](context = context)
        case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Double] =>
          startStrean[Double, Double](context = context)
        case _ =>
          startStrean[Map[String, Any], Map[String, Any]](context = context)
        }
```

What the previous code does is:

- Import the universe from `scala-reflection`. Documentation [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html)
- Type check using `quasiquotes`. Documentation [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/hygiene.html#) and [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/type-details.html#)
- Create the function with the TypeTags available at compiliation time

Comment: Just realized that quasiquote will take the argument as a Literal. So, it's not the same `val context = "Int"; tq"$context"` than `tq"Int"`

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
class MyParamClass[T](context: String) {
    def apply() {
        context match {
            case "Map[String, Int]"    => new MyParamClass[Map[String, Int]](context)
            case "Map[String, Double]" => new MyParamClass[Map[String, Double]](context)
            case _ => new MyParamClass[Map[String, Any]](context)
    }
}
```

}

You can then get typed class: `val clazz: MyParamClass[_] = new MyParamClass("Map[String, Long]")`

Comment: This won't actually give you a typed class where it counts, as evidenced by the underscore in your last snippet. Also, I think you meant to put the apply method in the companion object, and I think you meant to call that instead of the constructor. Not that any of that would help with the main problem.